# How to increase SharePoint Storage

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a maximum limit of a SharePoint online storage? I got notification on the site that it is running out of space. Currently the storage allocation is 1TB. Is there a way to increase it to maybe another TB? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1TB is the maximum size you can have for a site collection. If you need more space, you'll need to provision a new site collection, assuming your tenant has the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Check the versioning of Document librarys .... by deleting unwanted versions will maximize the utilization of storage....

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your question furthermore.
[Manage site collection storage limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)